# How do you snap?

Tags: edit-mode

In edit mode, I'd like to move one vertex along the y axis until it lines up, perpendicular to the y axis, with another vertex. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the *Snap to Vertex* option:

[image]

You don't have to activate the *Snap* tool itself, you'll just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to snap. Select your vertex, move on Y with <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to snap to the vertex you want while you point to this vertex:

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you!